# The object variable give back undefined

Tags: javascript

When I run code below error occurs - "Cannot read property 'drawGame' of undefined". Why?

```
function Game() {
    this.renderer = new Renderer(this.player);
    this.startGame();
}

Game.prototype.startGame = function() {
    this.renderer.drawGame(); //here error occurs
    setTimeout(this.startGame, 20);
};

function Renderer(){
}

Renderer.prototype.drawGame = function() {
    //function content
};
```

Comment: worked fine for me

Comment: Seems to work for me too.

Comment: it's because this is window object when you call setTimeout try `setTimeout(this.startGame.bind(this), 20);`

Comment: @jcubic Thank you, It's working now.

Comment: If you want to add code use` {}` button or indent it with 4 spaces. Also if you have code that can run in the browser you can use stack snippet (`<>` button).

Comment: @jcubic Thank you one more time. I'm new here, so I must get used to all feature of this site, I guess.